# Why script generated by SSMS shown in red is different from script stored in system tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Why script generated by SSMS shown in red is different from script stored in system tables. **Please notice stored procedure names in query, query result and Object explorer.**

[image]

i.e.
All these methods are giving me same script

```
sql_module
object_definition
sp_helptext
```

However when generated from SSMS, right click -> script as Create or Modify is giving a different script.

How is it possible and generating different scripts.

Comment: Looks like the same script to me, except that when you pick "Script as ... modify" you get `ALTER` instead of `CREATE`.

Comment: Please check procedure name carefully. I am getting same issue with 300+ stored procedures

Comment: I can see the difference now but please make it easier for us to help you in the future by explaining exactly what it is you want us to look at. I guess the $1000 question here is why the objectid for a procedure with a name that starts with an x refers to a procedure that doesn't.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, Thanks for pointing it out. Will take care going forward. Root cause of this is sp_rename as Rahul mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be confusing.

The Stored procedure `getBudgets4programManager2` was renamed (very likely using `sp_rename` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx), so the original definition does not match the new name. BTW. Notice that the definition stored in metadata will always change the DDL command to `CREATE` in case of issuing an `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement.

At the same time, SSMS scripting features will not simply get the definition from metadata as it has an object representation of the stored procedure, it will normalize the schema name & object name, and it may also normalize the DDL command accordingly (`CREATE`/`ALTER`). Notice that the schema is showing it is normalized (i.e. `[dbo]`), and that the current name is also normalized.

As for why the metadata definition is not renamed at the same time you rename the object. The answer is not 100% clear, but such change would affect any features in the SQL Server engine that relies on the definition, including using the `WITH ENCRYPTION` option on `ALTER/CREATE PROCEDURE` as well as the verification of digital signatures.

As far as I know, other elements in both versions of the scripts should remain intact (comments, blank spaces, etc.).

I hope this information helps.